# How to hide a certain object in blender 2.8?

Tags: python, objects, interface, outliner

`hide_viewport` seems to be the old `hide` option but how to toggle the "eye icon" like in prior versions?

The 'visibility property' is not exposed to `bpy` at the moment as confirmed with *medium priority* (2. March 2019 - https://developer.blender.org/T62062).

From wiki.blender.org:

```
obj = bpy.context.object
print("Object %s:\n\thide in viewport: %r\n\thide in render: %r\n\tis selectable: %r\n" %
      (obj.name, obj.hide_viewport, obj.hide_render, not obj.hide_select))
```

Is there any way to replace the old 'hide option' at the moment?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What's your question? You'd like to hide the object for rendering or in the viewport or both?

Comment: Hi, i like to find api by hiding object in viewport, but the api to close "little eye" but i not find . New hide_viewport make off  "frame" but i whant "Eye" close, like to click on eye with mouse

Comment: Doesn't `obj.hide_viewport = True` "close" the little eye?

Comment: Nope, it's showing an empty screen icon @batFINGER

Comment: Oh ok. Gives the alt-click result.  There is `obj.visible_get()` .. but not set.

Comment: obj.visible_get() what's the use?

Comment: Returns whether the object is visible or not @Andrea

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In final 2.80 you can do it:

```
obj.hide_set(state)
```

[Click here for a link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=hide_set#bpy.types.Object.hide_set)

Comment: Bingo. This is the one.

Answer (score 9):

I guess the *Outliner* isn't finished yet <s>and it's just showing the *wrong* icon</s>.

You can set [`Object.hide_render`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=hide_render#bpy.types.Object.hide_render) as well as [`Object.hide_viewport`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=hide_viewport#bpy.types.Object.hide_viewport) like  `Object.hide` and `Object.hide_render` in 2.7x versions.

Disable visibility in all viewports:

```
>>> bpy.context.object.hide_viewport = True
```

Disable the object in renders:

```
>>> bpy.context.object.hide_render = True
```

Disable the object in the viewport:

```
>>> bpy.context.object.hide_set(True)
```

<s>*Note: Might be a bug and worth to report that behavior.*</s>

Comment: think api is incomplete, because new system istance work with 2 type of hide in viewport, try to press "Alt" in outliner on the "Eye" is the perfectly "hide_viewport"

Comment: Then you'll need to wait or report that... @Andrea

Comment: Bug report or another type of report?

Answer (score 3):

**There is the operator.**

In addition to @brockmann's answer

```
>>> for a in C.screen.areas:
...     if a.type == 'OUTLINER':
...         break
...         
>>> a
bpy.data.screens['Scripting.001']...Area

>>> a.type
'OUTLINER'

>>> c = {"area": a}
>>> bpy.ops.outliner.hide(c)
{'FINISHED'}
```

which does the click "shut" the eye thing.

Also there is

```
C.object.visible_get()
```

to report the visibility of the object in the context.

Comment: so there is only the possibility to do it with the operator for now?

Comment: Not sure.  Once it is turned off via the operator I have no idea how to turn it back on... lol.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the current area to the *Outliner* and call `bpy.ops.object.hide_view_set()`:

```
# Set the area to the outliner
area = bpy.context.area
old_type = area.type 
area.type = 'OUTLINER'

# Select all objects in the current scene
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
   obj.select_set (True)

# Call the operator
bpy.ops.object.hide_view_set() 

# Reset the area 
area.type = old_type
```

Comment: This approach is risky: What if the object is not part of the current scene? Recommend iterate through `bpy.context.scene.objects`. FYI: Using the operator, especially *how* is already covered in batFINGER's answer.

Comment: Different operator but same applies... worth noting here is most operators can be called once to operate on all  selected objects, rather than calling each iteration. (which is the case for this op too)  ie have operator outside and after select loop.

Comment: thanks, @brockmann for the edit and idea. I will try to iterate over your idea and update it.

Comment: thanks @batFINGER I have updated the line.

Comment: Cheers.  Would go for the API methods `ob.hide_set()` etc, since they don't require an outliner being open or toggled to.  The question was asked at a very early stage of 2.8 release, before these were available.