# Efficient way to hide an object using python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if this is the most efficient way to hide an object using python?

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Cone'];
bpy.context.object.hide_viewport = True;

Is there a more efficient way to do this (since I have to turn on/off visibility many times for many objects), maybe something like:

bpy.data.objects['Cube'].visible_set(False); # visible_set doesn't exist unfortunately

Thanks.

Comment: Efficient in which context? What you'd like to do?

Comment: I have to repeat turning objects on and off constantly so I want it to be efficient speed wise.

Comment: Selected objects or random objects in the scene?

Comment: I have 12 objects which I turn on/off constantly.

Comment: Just asking because in case the objects are already selected it will be faster than having an extra loop to select geometry beforehand. ALSO: In case you'd like to render your "on/off" animation then you also need `hide_render` property. Again, if you'd like to have efficient as possible, provide more context. Related:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133470/31447

Comment: The objects are thruster plumes that are toggle on/off.  So they are not already selected.  The control system will determine which thrusters are turned on or off, then I select them and then turn them on or off.   Thanks.

Comment: Sounds fancy, I guess your control system is an AI deciding which thrusters turned on or off right? Just kidding - if you really know the names then just access each object by its name like: `bpy.data.objects['your_object_name'].hide_viewport = True`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  Thank you!