# How to know the ON / OFF state of eyes in outliner

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, outliner

The outliner has three object show / hide buttons as shown in the image below.

[image]

I learned about hide_select and hide_viewport on / off status as follows. But I don't know how to look at the eye icon.

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube.002']
print(obj.hide_select)
print(obj.hide_viewport)
```

How to know the ON / OFF state of eyes in outliner?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133468/how-to-hide-a-certain-object-in-blender-2-8

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy

obj =  bpy.data.objects['Cube.002']
#obj.hide_set(1)
obj.hide_get()
```

[See the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.hide_get)

Comment: That's quite inconsistent when you think about it. I wonder why they made it this way...

Comment: I tried with Blender2.8 but didn't wonk

Comment: @brockmann, why did you feel it's important to do this with the active object instead of the  'bpy.data.objects['Cube.002']' as in the script provided in the question? Is there a reason to prefer True or False instead of 1 or 0? I mean I really don't mind when people correct me, but I think there should be a reason for that that is more than personal opinion or preference only.

Comment: For readability and consistent. Since bool is a subclass of int and a key word. Using int to represent bool can somehow become ambiguity for people not familiar with python and common programming language. Not a good practice, but yeah, personal choice.

Comment: ditto, please reconsider using the boolean.  Re why they made it this way  It is no longer a property `ob.hide = True` as it can now be set on a per view layer basis  `ob.hide_set(True, view_layer=some_other_than_context_view_layer)`.

Comment: RE *index operator*: It's not about personal preference. Using the index operator `[<key>]` is a bad idea in general because of its nature. You probably know, if the key is not part of the actual dict (*bpy_prop_collection* in this case) the assignment results into a *KeyError*. The prefered way is using the get function: `dict.get("<key>")`  to test whether the key exists beforehand, so in this case `bpy.data.objects.get("Cube.002")`. However, *in reality you'll never check for any name* because the user might change it. I hope that's a good explanation @MartynasŽiemys

Comment: @brockmann, I think you should make it a separate answer and provide your suggestions and a complete explanation. "...in reality you'll never check for any name because the user might change it."  - this statement is incorrect. It's an assumption about the context of the situation and it is not based on anything. Situations where one needs to work with object names specifically are possible. In this case this 'bpy.data.objects['Cube.002']'  might only be a placeholder in work in progress, I don't think anyone should care about it. It doesn't matter.

Comment: It's not about correctness, rather avoiding errors. Do you really get my point? @MartynasŽiemys